# How can I create a loop of fetch based on conditions of result in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, http-post, puppeteer, request-promise

I just want to fetch data from multiple urls in a circle loop until the return data is less then the limited number of objects, every url return the array of data object, I would combine all of result in to an `postResponse` array.

```
let urlsample = "https://example.com/page";
let postResponse = await page.evaluate(async (urlsample) => {
  let promises = [], pagenumb = 1;
  var fetchNow = function () {
    fetch(urlsample + pagenumb + "&page_size=100").then(function (response) {
      response.json().then(rp => {
        promises.push(rp.data.list);
        if (rp.data.list.length < 100) {
          return promises;
        }
        else {
          pagenumb++;
          fetchNow();
        }
      })
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
  fetchNow();
  return Promise.all(promises);
}, urlsample);
console.log('Final response');
console.log(postResponse);//the console print []
//---------
postResponse.then(x => {console.log(x);});//the console print error then is not the function
```

My function is as above.I had tried many time to figure out the solution but seem stuck in how to use Promise.all in right way. Anyone can help me out?

Comment: You are awaiting the evaluate. You don't need to use `then`.

Comment: Hi, but console keep print out  []

Comment: If I follow the code, I see the declaration of `promises`, the fetchNow() which will return immediately, and then the function will return with no elements in promises.